# Work done involving two equal objects

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work

I just want to check my understanding. Say I have two equal mass blocks A and B, being pushed together by force $F$ by a distance $D$; ignore friction.

Technically, the total work by $F$ is $FD$, but really only half the energy goes to A, the other goes to B. Obviously because they are equal. But really isn't what's happening is $F$ is doing work on A but A is also doing work on B?

Or another way of saying this is $F$ does work on A, but the force from B does negative work as B is taking some of A's energy.

Comment: I am not able to understand the setup, could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Yeah just saying you have one(1) external force, pushing on two identical blocks, same mass, call them A and B, frictionless. As the force pushes, both A and B move together. I know that the work of F on A causes change in kinetic energy. Just curious if A also does work on B, such that B gets half the kinetic energy. I think that is what is happening, just checking my understanding

Comment: Is it something like force is applied on A and B is in front of A?

Comment: no, I think this is getting confused. Two block, inline A then B. Touching one another. Equal on a frictionless plane. You apply one force to A. If you looked at A, it would have F pushing to right, then a negative force -F/2 pushing from block B to the left So the Net work is F/2 times the distance. What i want to know is  the negative work done by block B, same as saying block A did positive work on B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or another way of saying this is F does work on A, but the force from
>   B does negative work as B is taking some of A's energy.

From Newton's third law A exerts a force on B and B exerts an equal and opposite force on A. That means the net force acting on A is not F, but F minus the force that B exerts on A. Since the net force on A is less than would have occurred without B being present, yes you can say that B is taking some of A's energy.

The acceleration of both A and B is given by

$$a=\frac{F}{M_{A}+M_{B}}$$

Since both blocks have the same acceleration, the force on B is

$$F_{B}=M_{B}a=\frac{M_{B}F}{M_{A}+M_{B}}$$

Since B exerts an equal and opposite force on A, the net force on A is

$$F_{A}=F-F_{B}=F-\frac{M_{B}F}{M_{A}+M_{B}}$$

$$F_{A}=\frac{M_{A}F}{M_{A}+M_{B}}$$

If the two masses are equal, then the net force on A is

$$F_{A}=\frac{F}{2}$$

And the work done on A is half of the work done on both A and B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: really then the reaction for from A on B, which is F/2, does work on B. That is why half the energy goes to A and the rest to B correct

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz That is correct. If you do a free body diagram on B you see that the only external force acting on B is the force exerted on it by A. So in effect half of the work done by the external agent $F$ is passed along to B by A with the other half done on A. Hope that helps.

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Then, of course, according to the work energy theorem the net work done on each A and B equals the change in kinetic energy of each, as noted by Wolphram jonny

Comment: awesome, thank you for clearing my confusion. Work is done on A, but because of B's interaction, A does work on B too. In full, the total work on the system equals the systems total kinetic energy. Or you can see that Some work goes to A and some to B, which ends up being the same. Thanks again!

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz I think you got it. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

So let's clearly see what is happening. There is a force that acts on A, and as it is in contact with B there is a contact force on B. Due to the force on the system A,B the net *acceleration* of the system is F/2m. Hence applying Newton's second law, we can say that the contact force will be equal to F/2. However that doesn't mean that the applied force C is directly acting on B. The applied force F does work on A only, while A does work on B and not the applied force F.

Hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: okay, lets look at just block B in the system. It has for F/2 on it, over distance x. So it has work done F/2x. So you say that is not right but yet just proved A does work on B, as B consumes it. See what i am saying

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz the force F doesn't act in B so force has just done work on A, and B's energy comes from A and not from the force F

Comment: Force F does act only on A, but force F/2 acts on B from A. So F/2 does work from A to B

Comment: Yeah but that F/2 is normal reaction and not direct action of F

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Your missing the point and adding confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can see the problem both ways, and both are correct. You can imagine the bodies separately, and calculate how much work F makes on A, it is F*D. That is not the total work on A because as you said, B is also doing (negative) work on A.

You can also imagine the two blocks together as if they were a rigid body. In such case F*D is the work made on the total system A+B.

So, imagining the work being done just on A or on the entire system is a matter of choice, but this will not change the results, for instance, the total change in kinetic energy due to the action of the force F.

Case 1:  $FD-F_BD=1/2m_A v_A^2$ and $F_BD=1/2m_B v_B^2$

Case 2:  $FD=1/2(m_{A+B}) v_{AB}^2$

You can easily see that the 3 velocities are the same

Comment: So what i originally asked was right Correct?  But in the end as you say, the total energy is the same, just a matter of how you break it down.

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your description is quite correct As force F is applied on the system of masses the objects shall move together (according to you) thus there shall exist a normal reaction force( say N) equally exerted on both blocks on object A It will do -ve work yet on object B it will do +ve work due to the difference of angles
Mathematically 
Work done on A is (F-N)(D)
Work done on B IS (N)(D)
on addition Net work done is (F)(D) which goes on to verify the fact that Sum of external forces on system are the only things that matter(here) and internal force sum upto zero in the calculation. Also indirectly force F is responsible to move block B

Comment: Normal reaction force is applied equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.